# Firebase onAuthStateChanged() skipping code

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an applications sign up feature using Firebase Authentication & Firestore. At the moment, when I create a user I want to also create a file in my Firestore. However, my `onAuthStateChanged()` function is simply skipping over this operation.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
       
    //User is signed in.
    if (user) {

        console.log("This happened.");

        //Create the Users document in the Firestore Database.
        firestore.collection("Users").doc(email).set({
            UserEmail: email,
            UserRole: role
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: " + error);
        });

        console.log("This also happened.");

        //Redirect user to the dashboard for their role.
        if(role === "Customer") window.location.replace("customer.html");
        else if (role === "Manager") window.location.replace("manager.html");
        else if (role === "Deliverer") window.location.replace("deliverer.html");
        else console.log("The value of role is not an accepted value: " + role + ".");

    }

});
```

Running this in the browser, I see both the "This happened." and "This also happened." console outputs, and receive no other console outputs or errors. It also completes the redirects at the bottom the if statement. I've been having lots of trouble with this function in this file as well as others, so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As you show it now, email is not being assigned.  Even so, consider using the user's UID as the id of the document instead of email.  Also consider if the page being changed is effectively stopping the execution of javascript in it, so that the Firestore operation never completes.

Comment: move the code into the `.then()` branch; else you'd defeat the idea of promises and asynchronous operation ...

Answer (score 0):

Any code that needs the user's login state must be inside the `onAuthStateChanged` callback. You've already done that, so you're halfway there.

Any code that must run after the data is successfully written to the database, must be inside the `then()` callback. So:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    //User is signed in.
    if (user) {
        //Create the Users document in the Firestore Database.
        firestore.collection("Users").doc(email).set({
            UserEmail: email,
            UserRole: role
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");

            //Redirect user to the dashboard for their role.
            if(role === "Customer") window.location.replace("customer.html");
            else if (role === "Manager") window.location.replace("manager.html");
            else if (role === "Deliverer") window.location.replace("deliverer.html");
            else console.log("The value of role is not an accepted value: " + role + ".");
            else console.log("The value of role is not an accepted value: " + role + ".");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: " + error);
        });    
    }

});
```